# How to download a file in R from a URL that requires a verification?

Tags: r, download, verification

I am trying to download the [Clinical Lab Fee Schedule from Medicare](https://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Payment/ClinicalLabFeeSched/Downloads/18CLAB.zip) programmatically through R.

```
library("readxl")

ZIPURL <- "https://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Payment/ClinicalLabFeeSched/Downloads/18CLAB.zip" 
CLAB_FileName <- "CLAB2018v1.xls"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file( ZIPURL,temp, mode="wb")
con <- unzip(temp, CLAB_FileName)
CLAB <- read_excel(CLAB_FileName,skip=1, col_names=TRUE)
unlink(temp)
```

To download the ZIP file, the website requires a user click the "Accept" button.  This verification step appears to interfere with the `download.file()` and thus the code downloads the html page instead. Is there an option or extra in R to bypass or enter a verification?

The responses I see from the commands are:

`download.file( ZIPURL,temp, mode="wb")`

> trying URL
>   'http://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Payment/ClinicalLabFeeSched/Downloads/18CLAB.zip'
>   Content type 'text/html' length 42502 bytes (41 KB) downloaded 41 KB

`con <- unzip(temp, CLAB_FileName)`

> Warning message: In unzip(temp, CLAB_FileName) : error 1 in extracting
>   from zip file

`CLAB <- read_excel(CLAB_FileName,skip=1, col_names=TRUE)`

> Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim =
>   shim,  :    Evaluation error: path[1](https://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Payment/ClinicalLabFeeSched/Downloads/18CLAB.zip)="CLAB2018v1.xls": The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Comment: check out https://www.cms.gov/robots.txt

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this can help.

Comment: its illegal to crawl the page.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the robot.txt, I've never seen one before and have learned something new. It looks like the filepath that @Level 3 Helmet supplied is not disallowed and so downloading the file I stated should be legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just download https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Payment/ClinicalLabFeeSched/Downloads/18CLAB.zip directly? Just make sure that the user knows and agrees to the licence beforehand.

Comment: Can I, yes. However, I would like to automate the process.

Comment: Yes - that is the direct URL that you can just pop into ZIPURL

Comment: This works great, thank you! I initially overlooked your URL as being the same as I provided, sorry.  May I ask how you found that precise path? I was able to find it myself by looking at the Page Source on the disclaimer page.

Comment: I guessed based on the URL parameter. Since it started with a / I removed everything to the left of it.